# ondblclick function to cancel onclick

Tags: java, html, onclick

I don't know anything about java nor html. I tried searching but didn't get it to work.
I found a recycle-bin gadget for windows 7 and I wanted it to open recycle-bin folder when `onclick` and empty when `ondplclick`.
Basically the bin.html `onclick="openBin();" ondblclick="emptyBin();` calls for these two function in the bin.js

```
function openBin() {
  System.Shell.execute('shell:RecycleBinFolder');
}

function emptyBin() {
    System.Shell.RecycleBin.emptyAll();
}
```

I wanted that when double click the gadget, it cancels the `openBin()`
I tried `Timeout`, read about `queue` and `Eventhandler` but could not get it to work.
As I said I am no coder.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're not a coder, I don't know what you expect people here to do. They're not going to write code for you

Comment: I believe this may be way above your current skill level and your requested functionality may be impossible to achieve.  Your referring to Javascript which does not have access to the clients file system.

Comment: @kmb385 - Yes, but [JScript does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I was hoping someone would point out some of the caveats to my statement.  Does HTML5 intend to allow access to the local system?  Another one that allows access is Active X.  I just realized the OP was talking about JScript

Comment: I didn't want to trouble anyone that much I just wanted a point in the right direction. Sorry if I did something wrong and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is so obtrusive javascript :(. Makes me sad panda.

Onclick event will be always triggered first so you will have to rethink what you want to do.

If you want to not-show open bin window maybe consider doing something like different logic in onclick. i suggest onclick -> opens bin , onclick with shift -> empty him.

this will only require adding if with alt key code pressed for it :)

You can read about keycodes in javascript more here http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested, here's how I solved it:

```
function openBin() {
t = true;
if (t) {
setTimeout("if (t) {System.Shell.execute('shell:RecycleBinFolder')}", 400);
}}

function emptyBin() {
t = false;
System.Shell.RecycleBin.emptyAll();
clearTimeout();
}
```

Comment: if someone is not as fast double clicker as you he will have problems :)